# Knowing the level of grid nesting in JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid, jqgrid, nested

I'm using JQGrid 4.0. In order to use a different CSS for the different level of nesting at the point where the column headers are generated, which is in my point at line 2039 of jquery.jqGrid.src.js.

```
thead += "<th id='"+ts.p.id+"_"+ts.p.colModel[i].name+"' role='columnheader' class='ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-"+dir+"'"+ tooltip+">";
```

I tried to look at the different variables and objects in the scope at runtime using Chrome development tools, but to no avail.

In my context, JQGrid is embedded in an enterprise framework and cannot easily be upgraded to a newer version. Otherwise, I would upgrade to Free-JQGrid.

Can it be done?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand correctly, what you need. Do you use [grid with subgrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid_as_grid) or what you mean under `level of grid nesting`? What you mean under "*Knowing* the level of grid nesting"? You can for example specify any custom option of jqGrid, for example, `level: 3`. You can get the option using `getGridParam` method in the same way like you can get any other parameter, like `datatype` or `colModel`. Or you want to implement [column grouping](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:groupingheadar) instead?

Comment: Yes, I mean subgrids. I need to modifiy the code in order to add a different class depending on the level of nesting of the subgrid.

Comment: Could you describe more exact, what classes you need to set? I don't understand, why you need to modify the code of jqGrid.

Comment: I found out I could add a class to the grid, which actually solved my problem. I didn't change the code of JQGrid. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't full understand you. I don't understand why you try to assign **class** to different grids. Assigning classes has sense only if you really need to apply CSS rules on the tables. One can associate information to grid *without* changing the DOM of the page. I wrote you before that you can use you custom option `level: 1` in the top level grid, `level: 2` in the next level grid and so on. If you have a grid for example `$("#" + gridId)` and you want to know the level of the grid, then you can just use `$("#" + gridId).jqGrid("getGridParam", "level")`. You will get 1 or 2.

Comment: The usage of `$("#" + gridId).jqGrid("getGridParam", "level") === 2` or `$("#" + gridId).hasClass("mygridlevel2")` (what you suggest) is almost the same, but by assigning class you inform the web browser to search for CSS rules and to apply there on child elements. The usage of `<table id="grid2" class="mygridlevel2"></table>` will work, but I'm not sure that it's the best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are following the [Subgrid as grid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid_as_grid) concept the sub-grids are created manually by you. So for each subgrd you can add an attribute indicating the level and when expanding for a new sub-level you can access this attribute from the parent.